# base_url function in Codeigniter isn't correct, contains FCPATH local root path

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I have just uploaded my website to the webhost and I realised the `base_url()` contains the value of the constant `FCPATH`, that points to the local root path

So, instead of printing **http://mywebsite.com/**
It prints something like **http://mywebsite.com/var/www/html/.../**

This is a linux host and it is printing the disc path to the root folder.

It works. It is generating a valid URL to the files (http://mywebsite.com/var/www/html/.../js/my.js is routed to the correct file)

But I was using that public url for other purposes on my website. Do you know what is going on? is that a normal behavior? Is there any other function or constant that I can use or do I have to subtract FCPATH from `base_url()`

Comment: base_url() is configured in the config file. What value did you put there?

Comment: Base url in the config is the public addrress, just put your public root there, use document root for inner paths

Comment: I understand but I'll need to change it everytime I change hosts. i just don't know why it works fine on localhost but fails on a remote server

Comment: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/config.html#environments see if that helps. Multiple configs for multiple environments

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your config file:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://". $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . preg_replace('@/+$@','', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']));
```